# How to make this function non-blocking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I need to make function s_settings not stopping programm, I call this function in async function, in `set_settings` I get data from the server in `send_settings` I send data to the server. I can't make methods(set_settings & send_settings) async. But I need to make this function non-blocking

```
def s_settings(id, _user_settings, all_settings):
    if 'category' in set_settings(str(id)):
        _user_settings[str(id)] = set_settings(str(id)) # Get from the Server
    print(user_settings)    
    _user_settings[str(id)]['category'].append(
        all_settings[str(id)]['category'])
    _user_settings[str(id)]['time_to_receive'].append(
        all_settings[str(id)]['time_to_receive'])
    _user_settings[str(id)]['language'].append(all_settings[str(id)]['language'])
    send_settings(_user_settings[str(id)], str(id)) # Send to the server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by `loop.run_in_executor()`

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a bummer. You have to model this function as a coroutine. But since you can't rely on the event-loop to poll the blocking function call to `send_settings` for you, you can spawn a separate thread where that function will execute. Your coroutine should be non-blocking with a way to poll that thread and get the result. It'll probably be quite a complicated implementation.